# Is there a way to verify that a Lazy loaded object is not in Hibernate session?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose there is a Parent class and I load it using `lazy = "true"`.

Is there a way to verify that the Set is not loaded in the memory before an explicit call is made for it?

```
public class Parent{
   private Intger parentId;
   Set <Child> child = new HashSet(); 
}
```

The child class:

```
public class Child{
   private Integer childId;
   Parent p; 
}
```

When I load Parent, and before I call `parent.getChild()`, is there a way to verify that the child is not loaded into the memory?

Comment: are you using JPA2..??

Comment: @ankur-singhal No Hibernate 5

Comment: @Pritam Banerjee one you call `parent.getChild()`, enable sql logging, and see it would be hitting your database to fetch agianst child id's

Comment: @PritamBanerjee also if you have some doubt, better post some code like particular entity you are targeting at

Comment: @ankur-singhal I have already enabled sql logging. That is not what I am looking for. I am trying to verify that this the child object is not loaded in memory. That is all.

Comment: Good question. Through the JPA API I think there is no chance, but some educated guesswork: using the Hibernate API method  [AbstractPersistentCollection.wasInitialized ?](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/AbstractPersistentCollection.html#wasInitialized--)

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for pointing me to right direction. I used `isInitialized()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test the application the following function was used:

```
Set<Child> childLazy = parentLazyLoaded.getChild();
Set<Child> childEager = parentEagerLoaded.getChild();

//then use the following methods
System.out.println("Lazy Loaded: " + Hibernate.isInitialized(childLazy));
System.out.println("Eager Loaded: " + Hibernate.isInitialized(childEager));
```

First one returns `false` and the second one `true`.